# python google maps

Tags: qt, location, pyqt, designer, geo

I m currently working with python and qt designer. **pyqt**

I am searching for a method to visualize a map and locations and tags on them. I have to find locations using adreeses, like u would search in a google map, multiple tags required on a single map. 
Ive already search some modules and have an idea what is geo coding and reverse coding. But dont have a clue what to do after u get ur lat and lon values using a bunch of adresses. 
Lets say, a list contains 20 addresses, using thesee adreses or using their lan and lon values, I want to display a map with all 20 addresses pinned on that very map.

Comment: You should post this as an answer instead of editing the _question_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to use google maps for this?  You could use the QWebView as the interface component and te google python API to feed the data to the view.  That would be my recommendation anyway.